# How to calculate texture coordinates for a cube?

Tags: graphics, javafx

I was reading about texture mapping on 3D shapes in javafx where I came across this code,

```
static TriangleMesh createMesh(float w, float h, float d) {
if (w * h * d == 0) {
return null;
}
float hw = w / 2f;
float hh = h / 2f;
float hd = d / 2f;
float x0 = 0f;
float x1 = 1f / 4f;
float x2 = 2f / 4f;
float x3 = 3f / 4f;
float x4 = 1f;
float y0 = 0f;
float y1 = 1f / 3f;
float y2 = 2f / 3f;
float y3 = 1f;
TriangleMesh mesh = new TriangleMesh();
mesh.getPoints().addAll(
hw, hh, hd, //point A
hw, hh, -hd, //point B
hw, -hh, hd, //point C
hw, -hh, -hd, //point D
-hw, hh, hd, //point E
-hw, hh, -hd, //point F
-hw, -hh, hd, //point G
-hw, -hh, -hd //point H
);

mesh.getTexCoords().addAll(
x1, y0,
x2, y0,
x0, y1,
x1, y1,
x2, y1,
x3, y1,
x4, y1,
x0, y2,
x1, y2,
x2, y2,
x3, y2,
x4, y2,
x1, y3,
x2, y3
);
mesh.getFaces().addAll(
0, 10, 2, 5, 1, 9, //triangle A-C-B
2, 5, 3, 4, 1, 9, //triangle C-D-B
4, 7, 5, 8, 6, 2, //triangle E-F-G
6, 2, 5, 8, 7, 3, //triangle G-F-H
0, 13, 1, 9, 4, 12, //triangle A-B-E
4, 12, 1, 9, 5, 8, //triangle E-B-F
2, 1, 6, 0, 3, 4, //triangle C-G-D
3, 4, 6, 0, 7, 3, //triangle D-G-H
0, 10, 4, 11, 2, 5, //triangle A-E-C
2, 5, 4, 11, 6, 6, //triangle C-E-G
1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 8, //triangle B-D-F
5, 8, 3, 4, 7, 3 //triangle F-D-H
);
mesh.getFaceSmoothingGroups().addAll(
0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5
);
return mesh;
}
```

How did the calculate and set up the texture coordinates for the cube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texture coordinates can be whatever you want them to be.

Usually for simple shapes you want the scale of the texture (that is, how big the texels will be in world space) on all sides to be the same, which means for this cube that each face gets the same area of the cube texture. We can see that all the coordinates used are multiples of 1/4 on the x axis and 1/3 on the y axis, so presumably they're all 1/4 by 1/3 rectangles (I haven't checked). Texture coordinates generally run from 0 to 1 regardless of the pixel size of the texture; this allows you to substitute a different resolution of texture without changing the coordinates.

Presumably each face of the cube gets its own non-overlapping piece of the texture. You can arrange the faces on the texture any way you like, but usually one chooses arrangements which put at least some adjacent faces of the cube adjacent on the texture as well; if done as much as possible, this is a *net* of the cube. The division of the texture into 3-by-4 tiles suggests that this is the case; since a cube has six faces 3-by-2 would be more suited for an efficient packing.

Finally, you generally want to make sure that the texture coordinates are  arranged in the same order for all faces (counterclockwise or clockwise) so that parts of the texture are not mirror-reversed, which makes painting the texture more inconvenient — unless your model actually has perfect mirror image sections (without any writing or such on them).

The above are just constraints to follow. There's lots of freedom beyond that.

If you're manually setting up coordinates as the above code does, then generally the way you start is by picturing one face of the model, and picking some region of the texture to go with it. Then you move along the vertices of the face and enter the corresponding texture coordinates, making sure that it's the right orientation. Then you do the same with adjacent faces in a consistent way, and continue until you've done all of the model.